# Facebook Graph API - Post Link to App

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've found a quite strange behavior if I try to post to a user wall (feed) using the graph API (tested with Python and JavaScript SDK):

If I include a valid facebook internal link including GET parameters (i.e. link to an app) the API fails with a HTTP status 500. If I use any other external link (with GET parameters) or an invalid facebook link or a facebook link without GET paramters, everythings works fine.

You can try this in the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=me/feed):

POST: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed

**Non-working Fields**:

- caption: 'test'
- message: 'test'
- link: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Lorem-Ipsum/159165434150059?sk=app_227540913924543

**Working Fields (invalid sk parameter)**:

- caption: 'test'
- message: 'test'
- link: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Lorem-Ipsum/159165434150059?sk=app_666

Any ideas? Or a suggestion how to post a link to a facebook app (i.e. http://www.facebook.com/pages/Lorem-Ipsum/159165434150059?sk=app_227540913924543)

Comment: all links are redirecting me to http://www.facebook.com immediately.. maybe the page is not there ;) I bet if you try https://www.facebook.com/pages/Lorem-ipsum/113228275356668 it will work :)

Comment: yeah, this were just (bad) non-public example urls. if you add a get parameter pointing to an app it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `sk` parameter use the `v` parameter eg:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Lorem-Ipsum/159165434150059?v=app_227540913924543

Comment: I don't know where this information is available. But I had a similar problem before. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about posting a link, but when uploading a photo, you cannot post a photo with a link from facebook domain. You must use an external resource.